# Discord.py PollBot Command with args

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
async def poll(ctx, *, message, arg1, arg2):
    pollem = discord.Embed(title='', description=f'{message}')
    pollem.add_field(name='one {0}'.format(arg1), value='')
    pollem.add_field(name='two {0}'.format(arg2), value='')
    msg=await ctx.channel.send(embed=pollem)
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    #await msg.add_reaction(emoji=':two:')
```

Thats my code so far,and I rly dont know how to bringt it to work like
.poll "message" "arg1" "arg2" "arg(n)"

Right now i just get errors.

> TypeError: poll() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'arg1' and 'arg2'

Comment: What are you trying to do? That `*` means that `message` includes every word. So you can't fill the `arg1` and `arg2`.

Comment: Ahh, i feel so dumb, fixed it!
But
```async def poll(ctx, message, *args) ``` Would work,right?

Comment: Yes it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Let the users use the command like `.poll Would you rather // Use arg 1? // Use arg 2?`
later you can split it.
use anything convenient other that `//` if you want

here is what you can do

```
async def poll(ctx, *, contents):
    message, arg1, arg2 = contents.split("//")
    pollem = discord.Embed(title='', description=f'{message}')
    pollem.add_field(name='one {0}'.format(arg1), value='')
    pollem.add_field(name='two {0}'.format(arg2), value='')
    msg=await ctx.channel.send(embed=pollem)
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    #await msg.add_reaction(emoji=':two:')
```